# Camera Crashing on Android 11 with IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-camera-intent, android-11

I am opening the camera and file chooser in my application. It's working fine in all versions including android 11. But in google pixel 5 with android 11, it's breaking while trying to open the camera. App not breaking but camera keep closing alert is showing and below exception is happening.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20210727_095347_634440296695227002.jpg

Java code :

```
  /***Camera or file chooser ***/
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 29) {
                file_path = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = null;
                boolean includePhoto = true;


                if (includePhoto)
                {
                    takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                    {
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = create_image();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", cam_file_data);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                        }
                        if (photoFile != null) {
                            cam_file_data = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                        } else {
                            cam_file_data = null;
                            takePictureIntent = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType(file_type);
                if (multiple_files) {
                    contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                }
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{
                            takePictureIntent
                    };
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, file_req_code);
                return true;
            } else if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

               Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                      
                    }
                   if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                      
                    } else {

                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }

                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");


                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};

                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }
        }

 private File create_image() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //getCacheDir();
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }
```

Call back

```
  /*******Camera Request Callback******/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null)
            {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            
                 if (intent == null) {
                 
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null)
                    {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }

            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                    file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
                    return;

                }
            }


            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                    if (null == file_path) {
                        return;
                    }

                    ClipData clipData;
                    String stringData;
                    try {
                        clipData = intent.getClipData();
                        stringData = intent.getDataString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        clipData = null;
                        stringData = null;
                    }

                    if (clipData == null && stringData == null && cam_file_data != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{
                                Uri.parse(cam_file_data)
                        };
                    } else {
                        if (clipData != null) { 
                            final int numSelectedFiles = clipData.getItemCount();
                            results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                results[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            }
                        } else {
                            results = new Uri[]{
                                    Uri.parse(stringData)
                            };
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            file_path.onReceiveValue(results);
            file_path = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == file_req_code) {
                if (null == file_data)
                    return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                file_data.onReceiveValue(result);
                file_data = null;

            }
        }


    }
```

Android manifest file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"
        />
```

Comment: I think this issue is related to the new storage mechanism with Android 11. Since you're creating a temporary file can you try storing it in the app's cache directory instead of `getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`. In that case you won't even need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Comment: Let me know, if it fixed it for you or not and upvote if you find this useflu

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`, as `Uri.fromFile()` has been banned, in effect, for five years. Use `FileProvider`, please. As a side benefit, it will clear up this problem.

Comment: @gtxtreme Can you share some sample code to use cache directory to store? Tried many codes with FileProvider. But some errors showing.

Comment: @CommonsWare  Only IllegalStateException happening.

Comment: That is because you added a hack to disable `StrictMode` somewhere in your app. [Here is an older example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Camera/FileProvider) showing `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. It is from [this free older book on Android app development](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.6-CC.pdf). [Here is a more modern example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.1/PdfProvider) of using `FileProvider` with `ACTION_VIEW` to view a PDF, from [this modern book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).